# resume paused gnome-shell from virtual terminal

Tags: gnome, process, resume

I tried to pause a long-running process using gnome's system monitor.
Unfortunately, when I clicked the menu, the process list rearranged and I managed to pause gnome-shell itself -- resulting in my GUI being stuck.

Is there any way to resume gnome-shell from a virtual terminal?

thanks.

Comment: Try `pkill -CONT gnome-shell`.

Comment: @harfel If this worked for you please accept muru's answer with the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others easily find the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming System Monitor sends the `SIGSTOP` signal to the `gnome-shell` process to pause it, you can tell it to resume by sending the `SIGCONT` signal:

```
pkill -CONT gnome-shell
```